# Columns with line-numbers by column-count

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

Hello,

I've created this view by CSS3 "column-count"-property just without line numbers. I works fine, but my question is how it would be possible to add line-numbers to such a view.

It seems not to be possible by CSS only.

What would be your solution to achieve this?

Comment: please add a minimal demo of this inside of your question. Especially a sample of the html and the css columns for the example in your image.

Comment: Please let us know what all things that you have tried so far. It will be great if you could share you existing code through JSFIDDLE.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the question and no code is shared - exact answer can not be given and that will too time consuming.

**Here is what you can try for**

1. Count total number of character in the textual content - paragraph
2. You will need to define how many columns that text will be devided into
3. Number of characters or letters that each line will be contain. (this will include every character such alpha-numeric + special + blank space)
4. You can write a JS which will count the number of characters and will print the COUNTER value after reaching the limit for each line.
5. In a way JS will just print the line number based on the number characters.

**Example**

1. Consider your textual content contains 1000 characters
2. Consider each line of the column will contain 25 characters
3. Which further means you will have 40 lines (1000/25) of text.
4. Consider there are 4 columns
5. Which further means each column will have 10 lines
6. You will need to consider \n explicitly to consider the end of line.
7. Once you know the number lines then you can run the for loops and line along with the row-numbers.